# How the set a closer range for an onEdit (e) function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to write a timestamp to different columns under specific conditions. The function should be executed within a Range. I would like to use line 13 as the header line.

This is how it should work:

Timestamp 1

If a cells are edited in column 8 or 9 from line 14, a defined time stamp ("HH:MM:SS") should be written in column 10 in the same line.

Time stamp 2

If a cells are edited in column 16 from line 14, a time stamp should be written in column 18 in the same line.

[image]

For this I use the code below. Unfortunately this does not work.

If I extend the range to the whole table, write the column captions (see: updateColName, timeStampColName) in the first line and define the "Header" variable as follows, then the code works.

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Link to a public version with reduced rows of the sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1otiQjBbQBUhAlULau0FR3wQYT0jvm8jJLNqnGYNMBoY/edit?usp=sharing

```
    function onEdit(e)
{ 

    var timezone = "GMT+2";
    var timestamp_format = "HH:mm:ss";
    var updateColName = "Watchlist";
    var updateColName1 = "Letzte Prüfung";
    var updateColName2 = "Entry Datum"; 
    var timeStampColName = "Letzte Änderung";
    var timeStampColName1 = "Letzte Änderung 2";
    var now = new Date()
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');
    var actRng = e.range;
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
      if (index>13) { 
    var headers = sheet.getRange(13, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());

    //Checks if column I has been edited and then writes a timestamp to column K in the same line
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
    var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;

      if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
        var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
        var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, timezone, timestamp_format);
            cell.setValue(date);
      }

    //Checks if column J has been edited and then writes a timestamp to column K in the same line  
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
    var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName1); updateCol = updateCol+1;

      if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
      var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, timezone, timestamp_format);
          cell.setValue(date);
      }

    //Checks if column Q has been edited and then writes a timestamp to column S in the same line
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName1);
    var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName2); updateCol = updateCol+1;

      if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { 
      var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
          cell.setValue(now);
      }
      }

}
```

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot of the Spreadsheet?

Comment: Screenshot attached above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your function has some minor mistakes.

To fix them, let's do the following:

1. Change `var headers = sheet.getRange(13, 8).getValues();` to `var headers = sheet.getRange(13, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());`
2. Change `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);` to `Utilities.formatDate(now, timezone, timestamp_format);`. No need to create a new Date() object.
3. Use the `e` event object to detect current changes. Change `var actRng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();` to `var actRng = e.range;`
4. Add a check on the start to verify if you are changing something below the headers:

```
var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
if (index>13) {
  //rest of the code   
}
```

## Final Solution:

Change the code to:

```
function onEdit(e)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+2";
  var timestamp_format = "HH:mm:ss";

  var updateColName = "Watchlist";
  var updateColName1 = "Letzte Prüfung";
  var updateColName2 = "Entry Datum"; 
  var timeStampColName = "Letzte Änderung";
  var timeStampColName1 = "Letzte Änderung 2";

  var now = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Tickerprüfung');

  var actRng = e.range;
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn()-1;
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  Logger.log(actRng);

  if (index>=13) { 
    var headers = sheet.getRange(13, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var cell;
    if (editColumn === headers.indexOf(updateColName) || editColumn === headers.indexOf(updateColName1)) {
      //Checks if column I has been edited and then writes a timestamp to column K in the same line
      //Checks if column J has been edited and then writes a timestamp to column K in the same line  
      cell = sheet.getRange(index, headers.indexOf(timeStampColName)+1);
    } else if (editColumn == headers.indexOf(updateColName2)) {
      //Checks if column Q has been edited and then writes a timestamp to column S in the same line
      var cell = sheet.getRange(index, headers.indexOf(timeStampColName1)+1);
    } else {
      return;
    }
    cell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(now, timezone, timestamp_format));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, with your suggested changes I don't get any timestamp. May be I did something wrong. I'll add the edited code with your suggestions above.

Comment: Hello @Dpei, you have to place the if check after you initialize the value editColumn with something.  Place it right after the `var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();` line.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have misread your code. I have updated my suggestion to reflect the correct solution.

Comment: I changed the code see above, but I'm still don't get any timestamp into my target columns... Any other ideas?

Comment: @Dpei could you please create a public copy of your spreadsheet and link it in your question? That way I can replicate your problem and determine what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You can find the link attached in the question above.

Comment: I've update the answer to contain the final working solution. You were missing a `getValues` on your header variable. @Dpei

Comment: Thank you very much. It's almost working now. The first IF condition after "if (index>13) {" works. The following ones are unfortunately not yet. I.e. only changes in column I are detected. Changes in the columns J and Q unfortunately not. Is it perhaps due to the nesting of the IF conditions?

Comment: Hello @Dpei, that was not the issue. There was some problems with the detection logic you were using. I have rewritten the function in a shorter form. Hope this helped you! Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Perfect! This is it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are declaring the headers in a wrong way:

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(13, 8).getValues();
```

This is only catching the value on the cell H13 (row 13, column 8)

If you want to get all the row values, you should do something like this:

```
var headers = sheet.getRange(13, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but now I got another problem. When the header line or cells above the header line are edited, the header gets overwrited and also the cells above gets overwrited with timestamps.

How can I get the the header line and range above the header line secured?